# The amount of memory used by the yarn does not match the amount of memory used by the actual machine

Tags: hdfs, hadoop-yarn, free

*I found that the amount of memory used by a node on the yarn UI is 8G, but actually use the free -h command to check the memory usage of 7.4G. What is the reason for the two memory inconsistencies?*

Comment: Which memory are you referring to?  YARN typically only shows RESERVED memory not memory in use.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct correlation between the memory seen through 'free -m/h' command on Linux and the container memory that is visible on the YARN UI. YARN works using the concepts of containers. So, the container has a mix of memory allocation and CPU allocation in terms of cores. During start of the process the free memory on server will be high and soon as the container allocation is done, the memory visible through 'free' command will reduce drastically. Actually, under the hood the memory has been allocated by YARN to the containers.